# How to set a Pydantic field value depending on other fields

Tags: python, pydantic

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Grafana(BaseModel):
    user: str
    password: str
    host: str
    port: str
    api_key: str | None = None
    GRAFANA_URL = f"http://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}"
    API_DATASOURCES = "/api/datasources"
    API_KEYS = "/api/auth/keys"
```

With Pydantic I get two unbound variables error messages for `user`, `password`, etc. in `GRAFANA_URL`.

Is there a way to solve this? In a regular class, I would just create `GRAFANA_URL` in the `__init__` method. With Pydantic, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Option A: Use a `@validator`

See the [validators documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/) for details.

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Model(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: str
    foobar: str = ""

    @validator("foobar", always=True)
    def set_if_empty(cls, v: str, values: dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        if v == "":
            return values["foo"] + values["bar"]
        return v


obj = Model(foo="a", bar="b")
print(obj)  # foo='a' bar='b' foobar='ab'
```

That way `foobar` remains a regular model field.

Note that for this to work, `foobar` must be defined *after* `foo` and `bar`. Otherwise you will have to use a [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#root-validators).

### Option B: Make it a `@property`

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: str

    @property
    def foobar(self) -> str:
        return self.foo + self.bar


obj = Model(foo="a", bar="b")
print(obj)         # foo='a' bar='b'
print(obj.foobar)  # ab
```

Then `foobar` will *not* be a model field anymore and therefore not part of the schema. That may or may not be relevant to you.

### Option C: Make it a `@computed_field` (*Pydantic v2 only!*)

Defining [computed fields](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/usage/computed_fields/) will be available for Pydantic 2.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field


class Model(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: str

    @computed_field
    @property
    def foobar(self) -> str:
        return self.foo + self.bar


obj = Model(foo="a", bar="b")
print(obj)         # foo='a' bar='b' foobar='ab'
```