# Making conditional variable with Pydantic's BaseSettings

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, pydantic

I am currently migrating my config setup to Pydantic's base settings. However I need to make a condition in the `Settings` class and I am not sure how to go about it:

e.g. I currently have:

```
class Settings(BaseSetting):
    name: str = "name"
    age: int = 25
```

and I want to add some logic like this:

```
class Settings(BaseSetting):
    name: str = "name"
    age: int = 25

    if age > 50:
        old_person: bool = True
```

What is the best way to go about this in pydantic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a Pydantic field value depending on other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301828/how-to-set-a-pydantic-field-value-depending-on-other-fields)

Comment: the answer for Pydantic v2 is in the link above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#root-validators). You probably also want to enable the `validate_assignment` option so that validations are run after changing an attribute via assignment:

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings, root_validator

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    name: str = "name"
    age: int = 25
    old_person: bool = False

    @root_validator
    def validate_old_person(cls, values):
      values['old_person'] = values['age'] > 50
      return values

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
```

If we run the following code:

```
# Creating an object with the defaults
settings = Settings()
print(settings)

# Create an object with an advanced age
settings = Settings(age=60)
print(settings)

# Create an object with the defaults, then modify it
settings = Settings()
settings.age = 60
print(settings)
```

The output is:

```
name='name' age=25 old_person=False
name='name' age=60 old_person=True
name='name' age=60 old_person=True
```

Comment: it seems root_validators got deprecated?

Comment: Yes, newer versions of Pydantic now use a type-annotation based system for defining validators. See [the documentation for details](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/), and also the [notes about the changes around validators in 2.x](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/migration/#changes-to-validators).